# How to gain access to all of an elements props when passing down props without having to list them in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am passing down props to an input and having to list each input prop to get it to work.

So I have a component like so that has an input:

```
<input 
   type={this.props.type}
   className={this.props.className}
   style={this.props.style}
   placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
   onChange={this.props.onChange}
   value={this.props.value}
   defaultValue={this.props.defaultValue}
   name={this.props.name}
/>
```

This component does a lot more but that is unrelated to the point of this post. Anyway is there a way to not have to type all of this out and kind of make it automatically accept the prop values? I tried doing something like `{...this.props}` inside the input and it did not work.

Comment: "I tried doing something like {...this.props} inside the input and it did not work." what do you mean by "did not work"? Did it throw? `<input {...this.props} />` should work.

Comment: Is it a class component or a functional component? If it's a functional component then {...props} would do the job.

Comment: I was passing wrong props down with the input props as well so it broke it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work, as long as the props object keys are the same as the possible props of the input:

```
<input {...this.props} />
```

Where props has a shape like:

```
{
   type,
   className,
   style,
   placeholder,
   onChange,
   value,
   defaultValue,
   name,
   //other input element attributes
}
```

Comment: I see the problem now I was passing non-input props down and that was breaking it. Thank you